# Serilog used with Prism 8 and Injecting Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger

Tags: prism, unity-container, serilog, ilogger

Using .Net 5 WPF, Serilog and PrismLibrary 8 with Unity
Can someone please guide me in the right direction so I can inject Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger into ViewModels etc.
I have found many snippets, but all fails on some point or another.
I prefer using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger for flexibility in coice of logging provider.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for some sort of example too. But I believe most of them use the ILoggerFacade and they since removed it for Prism 8. At the moment I'm using MAUI and it could be similar for WPF. I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WicmnH72kf0 but I did some changes for it to work with Prism.

You're gonna want to add nuget extension: Prism.Container.Extensions

Then add the following code (which is based off of Gerald's video) in  your PrismStartup or wherever you have your RegisterTypes:

```
   containerRegistry.RegisterServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddTraceLogger(_ => { }));
        });
```

Wherever you want to log add:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class IWantToLogHereClass 
{ 
   private readonly ILogger<IWantToLogHereClass> _logger;

   public IWantToLogHereClass(ILogger<IWantToLogHereClass> logger)
   {
      _logger = logger;
   }

   //...

   //whatever place you want to log
   _logger.LogInformation("HELLO WORLD!");

   //...
}
```

This did it for me, hope this helps!